# How to get python-x (eval-in-repl) to work?

Tags: python, spacemacs, repl

I'm looking to be able to do the same thing as `ESS` but for python, ie to be able to have two windows side by side one with python shell and the other with text file and send current line or block pressing C-enter or C-p. So I tried to install `(python-x)` but I don't seem to be able to do that, I tried to install `(eval-in-repl)` (all this through the MELPA system) but none of it seems to work as when I select `python-mode or python-activate` nothing happens, and when I open `M-x shell` then split windows with a python file `C-ret` isn't binded. Me adding `(python-x-setup)` in my `.spacemacs` raise an error at the start.

Any idea how I am supposed to install and setup a package so I can send lines to python shell (or any shell in general) ? I got spacemacs based on emacs 25.1.1

I can run `run-python` however it opens a shell but how do I get to feed it from a persistent text file ?

Comment: Doesn't `C-c C-p` open a python shell in `.py` file and then `C-c C-c` `python-shell-send-buffer` or `C-c C-r` `python-shell-send-region` work?

Answer (score 2):

Elpy can do that https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy

The command you are looking for would be `elpy-shell-send-current-statement`.

You can also try `elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer`

> Send the active region or the buffer to the Python shell.
>
> If there is an active region, send that. Otherwise, send the whole
>   buffer.

Comment: I can't manage to install it, I've followed the instructions, but where am I supposed to put `(package-initialize)
(elpy-enable)`, when I put in `.spacemacs user-config` I can't start emacs but when I put in `user-init` I have no `elpy` command that are available.

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about spacemacs.

Comment: It was my bad I didn't know that I had to add the package in the `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` it's all good now with python-x

Answer (score 1):

Install `eval-in-repl` from MELPA and configure it as described in the readme at https://github.com/kaz-yos/eval-in-repl/blob/master/README.md

Current instructions from the readme suggest

```
;;; Python support ;; 
(require 'python) ; if not done elsewhere 
(require 'eval-in-repl-python)
 (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
 '(lambda ()
 (local-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") 'eir-eval-in-python)))
```

for python support.

Answer (score 0):

I use `python-shell-send-buffer-switch` it's provided by the python layer in spacemacs (python-mode I assume?). It's bound to `, s B` and opens and runs your code in a python shell. You can choose python or python3 by customize the variable `python-shell-interpreter`